# SQL Query: Grouping results from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join

Hello and thanks in advance. I have two tables:

**users**

```
|- ID -|- NAME   -|
|- 1  -|- Will   -|
|- 2  -|- Isabel -|
|- 3  -|- Robert -|
|- 4  -|- John   -|
|- 5  -|- David  -|
|- 6  -|- Eric   -|
```

**tasks**

```
|- ID -|- USER -|- DESCRIPTION         -|
|- 1  -|- 1    -|- Clean floor         -|
|- 2  -|- 1    -|- Clean windows       -|
|- 3  -|- 2    -|- Repair an appliance -|
|- 4  -|- 3    -|- Buy spare parts     -|
|- 5  -|- 1    -|- Remove stains       -|
|- 6  -|- 2    -|- Pick up the lounge  -|
```

I need some help to write a query for get an array grouping "tasks" by "user", something like the following one:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user] => 1
            [tasks] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [description] => Clean floor
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [description] => Clean windows
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [description] => Remove stains
                        )
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [user] => 2
            [tasks] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [description] => Repair an appliance
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 6
                            [description] => Pick up the lounge
                        )
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [user] => 3
            [tasks] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [description] => Buy spare parts
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: I might expect that a simple left join between your tables would be workable here.  Have you tried a query yet, and can you share your PHP code?

Comment: make your select join first, then reformat the array in your desired structure

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't have "arrays".  Perhaps using `group_concat()` will do what you want:

```
select t.user,
       group_concat(t.id, ':', t.description order by t.id) as tasks
from tasks t
group by t.user;
```

Comment: Apologies for my bad expression and description of the environment. Of course I was referring to getting the array in PHP. This answer is exactly what I needed. Tested and working. Thanks a lot.